# Git merge made by recursive ? Why I cannot fetch the updated contrib module?

Tags: 7, version-control

I am using git repositories to keep Drupal core and contrib modules in sync.

The set up looks like this:

[drupal.org git repository] -> **[my-contrib repository] >> [my-dev-site repository]**

Recently I updated *my-contrib repository* with the latest dev version of one of contrib modules from drupal.org.

When trying to update my dev site repository from my-contrib repository I run

```
git fetch origin
```

Normally this works fine but today I received this message:

> Already up-to-date! Merge made by recursive.

I compared both repositories and I can see there is no updated contrib 
module in the *my-dev-site* repository.

How to correct this ? Why I cannot fetch the updated contrib module ?